# Google Sheets: count the number of columns with data in them

Tags: google-apps-script

In Sheets Scripts Editor, how do I count the number of columns with data in them in a specific sheet?

Comment: Does the sheet has blank cells in the first row between the first and the last column with data?  P. S. Please show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do that:

### Code

```
const columnsWithData = () => {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const range = sh.getDataRange()
  const values = range.getDisplayValues()
  const transposeCheck = values[0].map((_, iCol) => values.map(row => row[iCol]).some(cell => cell))
  const countBoolean = transposeCheck.filter(Boolean).length   
  return countBoolean  
}
```

### Explained

This is how the scrip reads:

1. get active sheet
2. get the data range

   - this already reduces the number of none empty columns
3. get the values

   - if you want to ignore the values, shown by formulae, then you can use `getValues()`
4. transpose the array and check whether a cell in the column range is not empty

   - [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) stops as soon as the statement is true
   - [`transpose`](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_transposition#ES6)
5. get the count by filtering for true

   - [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)
6. return the count

Comment: Thanks Jacob, just running into an implementation problem [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153115/google-sheets-script-error-referenceerror-concatenate-is-not-defined)

Comment: @Steve this is a cascade problem and not part of the solution I provided.