# ReferenceError: CONCATENATE is not defined

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am receiving an error when manually running this function:

```
function updateCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetSummary = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  const columnsWithData = () => {
    const range = spreadsheetSummary.getDataRange()
    const values = range.getDisplayValues()
    const transposeCheck = values[0].map((_, iCol) => values.map(row => row[iCol]).some(cell => cell))
    const countBoolean = transposeCheck.filter(Boolean).length   
    return countBoolean  
  }
  var spreadsheetCommunityGroups = ss.getSheetByName('Community Groups');
  var cellValueCommunityGroups = spreadsheetCommunityGroups.getRange('A12').getValue();
  var summaryCommunityGroups = CONCATENATE('B', countBoolean++);
  spreadsheetSummary.getRange(summaryCommunityGroups).setValues(cellValueCommunityGroups);
}
```

> Error: ReferenceError: CONCATENATE is not defined

I've turned on "API GOOGLE APP SCRIPT" for my account: https://script.google.com/u/0/home/usersettings.

Is `countBoolean` not being output in the CONCATENATE function?

Comment: The error stems from `var summaryCommunityGroups = CONCATENATE('B', countBoolean++);`. You can write `'B'+countBoolean++` instead.

Comment: Thanks @JacobJanTuinstra, I now receive `ReferenceError: countBoolean is not defined`.

Comment: @ruben added it again, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
const updateCells = () => {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const spreadsheetSummary = ss.getSheetByName('Summary')
  const range = spreadsheetSummary.getDataRange()
  const values = range.getDisplayValues()
  const transposeCheck = values[0].map((_, iCol) => values.map(row => row[iCol]).some(cell => cell))
  const countBoolean = transposeCheck.filter(Boolean).length   
  const spreadsheetCommunityGroups = ss.getSheetByName('Community Groups')
  const cellValueCommunityGroups = spreadsheetCommunityGroups.getRange('A12').getValue()
  const summaryCommunityGroups = 'B'+countBoolean
  return spreadsheetSummary.getRange(summaryCommunityGroups).setValues(cellValueCommunityGroups);
}
```